# Transcendence degree over rings

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I read an article on Arxiv (The Transcendence Degree over a Ring) where a transcendence degree over rings is defined using "submonic polynomials" with respect to a given monomial ordering. There exists in literature a generalization of transcendence degree over a ring (or just over integral domains) with no assumptions on the polynomial except for their (coefficients to be in the smallest ring), as in the usual field case? I've never find something on the topic, only the already mentioned paper and a generalization of transcendence degree of a domain over a subfield (See Milne), where the author uses the transcendence degree of the corresponding quotient field.

Comment: The introduction to the paper you refer to mentions some literature on the topic; in particular, its references [5] and [6] seem like they would probably say something about the definition you propose (and perhaps why it is not so well-behaved).

Comment: Reference [6] gives a definition of the transcendence degree of an ordered set of elements of a polynomial ring over the ring of its coefficients. I'm not interested in this case, but I need to answer a more general question. In the definiton of transcendence and transcendence degree over a field, may I replace field extensions with arbitrary ring extensions? On the other hand, reference [5] defines the transcendence degree of a domain over a subdomain, using the corresponding quotient fields.